# Making an outbound call and bridging both into a conference

Tags: twilio

I have what I think is a bit of a strange situation. I'm wondering if this is possible.

I need to:

1. Place an outgoing call from a browser to [number]
2. Ensure the person placing the above call hears the normal ringing sound
3. If the person at [number] picks up the phone, I need to place both
   the caller and the person called into a conference room named after
   the CallSid that identifies the called person's call

I initially thought I could dial the person on the browser directly into a conference, and then create a new call on my backend to [number] with the url set to twiml that will place them into the conference when they pick up the phone. The problem with this approach, though, is two-fold.  First, the browser caller won't hear the ringing sound for the entire duration before the called person picks up, they'll hear one dial and then nothing when they're placed into the conference. Second, I don't have the called person's CallSid at that point, so I can't put them into the correct conference.

Perhaps another way to phrase this question is: I want personA to make an outgoing call to personB from the browser. When personB picks up, I want them to join a conference named after their CallSid. Then, I want personA to be added to that same conference.

Note: I did try simply doing a normal direct call from personA to personB, and then moving them both into a conference once they're connected, but attempting to do this resulted in either personA or personB being dropped once the other one was moved into a conference.

Any suggestions about how to go about doing this?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643800/twilio-how-to-move-an-existing-call-to-a-conference