# Twilio - Is there anyway I can dial in a participants?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I tried doing this [Twilio - How to move an existing call to a conference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643800/twilio-how-to-move-an-existing-call-to-a-conference) but I can only dial in one extra participant I want to add 10 more people.

Comment: Are you asking how to add more participants into a Conference resource? If so, you have to get your new Conference SID and modify the Conference resource using your preferred method/system. You can find the Conference SID by searching for its `friendlyName` (provided it is unique/and/or "in-progress" `status`) and using the first result found as your Conference object, which you then access its `participants` `create( CALLER, CALLED_NUMBER, [ OPTIONS ] )` instance.

Comment: Thx @JohnSmith ! I want to dial a participant in the conference call  and not have him dial in. Any example I can see?

Comment: Check out https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource for how to do this using the Twilio REST API. I am only familiar with the PHP API but there are other frameworks Twilio uses (Node.js I believe for JavaScript, which may suit your case if I assume correct that `twilio-click-to-call` is a web-based implementation of such).